# How to get person to move by checking adjacent squares instead of manually inputting them in prolog?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, wumpus-world

I am trying to write a Prolog application were an archer will move into an adjacent square that is safe on a grid that is in a **4 x 4** system, this should be done by archer itself, for example if the square **above** the archer is safe he will move into it, if it is not safe he will check the square to the **right** and if it is safe he then will move into it.

The archer starts in the cell 4,1 and there is currently a **breeze** square above and to the right of the archer. A **breeze**, **gold**, **glitter** is what is in each square so archer is in square **4,1** **breeze** is in 3,1 and 4,2.  So far I have the user types in the co-ordinates that they want to go to, e.g. if I type in `safe_square(4,1,3,1).` the archer will move from **4,1** to **3,1** because the cell is safe.

But this is not a good way of doing this because the archer himself should check all adjacent options and then choose for itself what cell to go into.  What I have done is ordered the `safe_square()` in a way that the archer will check for the **gold** first, the **glitter** second, **empty** next and then **safe** last. This is what it should do but because the users themselves have to enter in where they want to go the code is irrelevant .

Here is how I am doing it at the moment:

```
safe_square(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N) :-
maxBound(N),
adjacent(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N),
safe(X,Y),
      move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
retract(show(L)),
append([[X,Y]],L,NewL),
assert(show(NewL)).

move(Xa,Ya,X,Y) :-
retract(square(Xa,Ya,ListFrom)),
delete(ListFrom,a,Existing),
retract(square(X,Y,ListTo)),
append([a],ListTo,NextPositionList),
assert(square(Xa,Ya,Existing)),
assert(square(X,Y,NextPositionList)),
!.

at(X1,Y1,E) :-
square(X1,Y1,L), member(E,L).

safe(X,Y) :-
square(X,Y,L),
\+ member(p,L),
\+ member(w,L).

adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,_) :- Ar is R -1,  Ar >= 1,  Ac is C.
adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,N) :-  Ar is R + 1,  Ar =< N,  Ac is C.
adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,_) :-  Ac is C - 1,  Ac >= 1,  Ar is R.
adjacent(R,C,Ar,Ac,N) :-  Ac is C + 1,  Ac =< N, Ar is R.
```

How can I do this without the users input?

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
safe_square(X,Y,L) :-
maxBound(N),
adjacent(Xa,Ya,X,Y,N),
gold(X,Y),
    move(Xa,Ya,X,Y),
retract(show(L)),
append([[X,Y]],L,NewL),
assert(show(NewL)).
```

And I tried this too:

```
at(X,Y,E) :-
square(X,Y,L), member(E,L).
```

Comment: If you care to, might be nice to explain what breeze, gold, glitter, etc. are about and how this project is graded.  A minor question is why is safe_square/5 defined with two identical terms of adjacent/5?  Some code is missing.  In general, Prolog is good for searching a space of solutions.  If you want to prioritize certain steps, that sounds like an algorithm you need to develop first.

Comment: a breeze, gold, glitter is what is in each square so archer is in square 4,1 breeze is in 3,1 and 4,2